# PHP SOAP Error Premature end of data in tag html line 1

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

Sample of the XML request and my code below:

XML

```
<GetInventory>
<ClientID>API_ClientID </ClientID>
<UserID>API_UserID </UserID>
<Password>API_Password </Password>
<SecurityKey>API_SecurityKey</SecurityKey>
<Item>
    <SKU>7003</SKU>
</Item>
<Item>
    <SKU>7046</SKU>
</Item></GetInventory>
```

PHP

```
$options = array(
    'exceptions' => 0,
    'trace' => 1
);

$client = new SoapClient($soap_url, $options);

$clie_info = array(
    'ClientID' => $client_id,
    'UserID' => $user_id,
    'Password' => $password,
    'SecurityKey' => $security_key,
    'Item' => array('SKU' => 'XX-XX-XX-XXXX-XXXX-10')
);

$result = $client->GetInventory($clie_info);

print_r($result);
```

Above is my simple request to a SOAP service.
In response I get:

> Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://xxx.xxx.com/v4/sandbox/xxxxx' : Premature end of data in tag html line 1 in D:\xxx\xxxxx\xxxx\api_3linx.php on line 15

Line 15 being:

```
$client = new SoapClient($soap_url, $options);
```

My question is: am I doing something wrong, or should I point the finger on the other end - the SOAP service support?

Comment: Add option to SoapClient constructor: trace => true.
Surround $client->GetInventory with try/catch and in catch use $client->__getLastRequest() to see actual request.

Comment: The parser doesn't even reach the line where it is:

$result = $client->GetInventory($clie_info);

It stops executing at line 15.

Comment: Can you post WSDL file? It looks like it might be invalid or have some sort of syntax error. For development please change 'exceptions' config setting to 1.